# Do something after a series of timeouts in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a function and remove a class before routing the user to the clicked link.

The HTML is simple

```
<div class="blurred-box opaqueNotInView">

    <div class="user-login-box">

        <span class="user-icon"></span>
        <div class="user-name">Admin</div>

        <button type="submit" class="user-password"><a class="goto"
            href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The JS looks like this:

```
$(".goto").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var time = 500;
    $('.blurred-box').each(function(i) {

        var row = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            row.removeClass("notOpaqueInView");
            row.addClass('opaqueNotInView');
            console.log("bye");

        }, time);
        time += 500; // everything works as intended until here

    });

    window.location = $(this).attr('href'); // goes straight to the href, no animation , no console log
    window.location = e.target.attr('href'); // gives e.target.attr is not a function, executes the animations and console logs, but does not go to the link
});
```

What is wrong here?

I just want to prevent the default link behaviour, then run the each/setTimeout structure and then go to `href="/auth/logout"`.

No codepen, as this is a nodeJS project.

Comment: Put the location assignment in the setTimeout callback. Make sure `e.target` is wrapped in a jquery function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox
You said Make sure e.target is wrapped in a jquery function. Well, how to do that?

Comment: You see how you’ve done `$(this)`? You’ve wrapped the “this” keyword in a jquery function. Also, don’t do it twice as there’s no need.

Comment: As a sidenote, not wrapping the `e.target` in a jQuery object makes that line of code even simpler:  `window.location = e.target.href;`.

Comment: Sidenote 2: You **cannot have a link (or any other interactive content, like a label, or a checkbox, or a select element) inside a button, and vice versa.**

Comment: @ptts Hi, I don't think its fair you've accepted the answer from `AnonymousSB` because they have copied my answer. Also, their answer doesn't allow the final class addition/removal to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I boiled your code down to the basics and have provided a demo. The key here is to find out how many `blurred-box` you have, and then adding the redirect to the end. Also, I start `time` at 0, and add `500` each time a `setTimeout` is called per `blurred-box`.

```js
$(".goto").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  time = 0;
  boxCount = $('.blurred-box').length;
  $('.blurred-box').each(function(i) {
    var row = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      row.removeClass("notOpaqueInView");
      row.addClass('opaqueNotInView');
      
      if (i == boxCount - 1) {
        console.log('bye');
       window.location = e.target.href;
      }
    }, time+=500)
  });
});
```

```css
.notOpaqueInView { background-color: red }
.opaqueNotInView { background-color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="goto">Stack Overflow</a>
<section class="blurred-box notOpaqueInView">
  Blurred Box 1
</section>
<section class="blurred-box notOpaqueInView">
  Blurred Box 2
</section>
<section class="blurred-box notOpaqueInView">
  Blurred Box 3
</section>
```

Comment: `var url = $(this).attr('href');` can be omitted and the code then simplified to `window.location = e.target.href;`.

Comment: I'd consider it very important you add information about interactive content not being allowed to nest.

Comment: @connexo, this was just a test setup as far the mark up is concerned, I have removed the button element and it still does not work.

Comment: @AnonymousSB
Your reply comes closest to what I want to achieve, I know that the this points to window in setTimeout.
What I want is, before going to the href, the row.addClass('opaqueNotInView'); to be executed every 500ms (and a console log message) before going to the link.
No matter where window.location = e.target.href is, it goes straight to the link, before logging or changing the classes.

Comment: Take a look at my updated code, should fit your needs, now that it's clear.

Answer (score -1):

The key additions are this:

```
var set = $('.blurred-box');
var length = set.length;
```

and

```
if(i === length-1){

    setTimeout(function(){ // allow the last class addition/removal to be seen

        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location = e.target.attr('href');

    },500)
}
```

Full working code:

```
$(".goto").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var set = $('.blurred-box');
    var length = set.length;

    var time = 500;
    $('.blurred-box').each(function(i){
        var row = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            row.removeClass("notOpaqueInView");
            row.addClass('opaqueNotInView');
            console.log("bye");

            if(i === length-1){

                setTimeout(function(){ // allow the last class addition/removal to be seen

                    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
                    window.location = e.target.attr('href');

                },500)
            }

        }, time);
        time += 500;

    });
});
```